# jQuery value of variable is [object Object]

Tags: jquery

If the form field is empty, the value of `cityName` should be displayed.
The value should be displayed before the user types his own value in and if he deletes the input, the `span` should change back to the default value (in my case 'London' as string).

I was playing around with `.prop('outerHTML')` and `$("#messageOutput")[0].outerHTML`, but this didn't work and the output remains `[object Object]` after the users deleted his input. Before the first input in the form field, the `span` is empty.

```js
var cityName = 'London';
console.log(cityName);
var messageVar = $('#messageInput').bind('input keyup', function() {
  if (messageVar.val().length == 0) {
    $('#messageOutput').text(cityName);
    console.log(cityName);
  } else {
    $('#messageOutput').text(this.value);
    cityName = messageVar;
    console.log(cityName);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="messageInput" />
<span id="messageOutput"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[object Object]` is coming from `cityName = messageVar;`

In prior lines you use `messageVar.val()` to get the value but in that line you are assigning the whole jQuery object , not it's value, to `cityName`.

When you try to stringify an object you get `"[object Object]"` as output.

As for initial page load you can trigger one of the events to get the event handler to set the text.

Following is a bit more straightforward version that also does the initial event trigger. Note also that `bind()` is deprecated in favor of using `on()`

```js
var cityName, originalCity = 'London';

$('#messageInput').on('input keyup', function() {
  const val = this.value.trim();
  // use input value if it has length or use the original
  cityName = !!val.length ? val : originalCity;
  
  $('#messageOutput').text(cityName);
  
  console.clear()
  console.log(cityName);

}).trigger('input')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="messageInput" />
<span id="messageOutput"></span>
```